# Extract certain properties from all objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects with the same properties. Each object has around a hundred properties. I want to keep only a handful of them in a new array:

```js
const dummyArray = [
    { "att1": "something", "att2": "something", /* … */, "att100": "something" },
    { "att1": "something", "att2": "something", /* … */, "att100": "something" },
    // …
  ];
```

How can I `filter`, `map`, `reduce` the array, or use some other method to extract the desired keys?

```js
const newDummArray = dummyArray.map(function(item) { 
    delete item.att1; 
    delete item.att3; 
    delete item.att15;
    // Long list …

    return item; 
  });
```

How can I keep only `att20`, `att30`, `att70`, `att80` for each object and delete the rest?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to get the properties, and generate a new object using [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015):

```js
const dummyArray = [{ "att20": "att20", "att30": "att30", "att70": "att70", "att80": "att80"}, { "att20": "att20", "att30": "att30", "att70": "att70", "att80": "att80"}];

const result = dummyArray.map(({ att20, att30, att70, att80 }) => ({
  att20, 
  att30, 
  att70, 
  att80
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 8):

map creates a new array, so there is no need to delete any thing, instead create an array of *interesting keys* and return it

```js
var dummyArray = [{
  "att1": "something",
  "att2": "something",
  "att20": "something",
  "att100": "something"
}, {
  "att1": "something",
  "att2": "something",
  "att20": "something",

  "att100": "something"
}];

let x = dummyArray.map((item) => {
  return {
    attr20: item.att20
  }

})

console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 8):

store the props you want to keep in an array then for each object transfer wanted props to a new object.

```js
var dummyArray = [{ "att1": "something", "att2": "something", "att100": "something"}, { "att1": "something", "att2": "something", "att100": "something"}];

var propsToKeep = ["att1", "att100"];

var result = dummyArray.map(item => {
  const obj = {};
  for (const prop of propsToKeep) {
    obj[prop] = item[prop];
  }
  return obj;
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is fine for a general purpose function, but inefficient when the list of keys is known apriori.

Comment: @Alnitak well yeah, but i.e. in ori-dori and brk solutions there's code duplication (key names are repeated). I think code duplication (and any premature optimization mess) is worse than a bit slower but more flexible code

Answer (score 6):

**I have find easiest way to do this** [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.

```js
    const odata = [
      { "id": "0001", "type": "donut", "name": "Cake", "ppu": 0.55 },
      { "id": "0002", "type": "ansd", "name": "EARK", "ppu": 0.67 }
    ];
    const outdata=JSON.stringify(odata,['id','type']);
    console.log(outdata);
```

Comment: Syntax similar to Lodash [`_.pick()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#pick) method

Comment: that's even more simple and easiest to apply!! tnx

Comment: Accept the answer, if this is work for you. @SajjadHossainSagor

Answer (score 2):

Here a function that take an object, and extract only the properties that you want. Which you passe through an array as a second parameter.

Advantage: more straight forward and cleaner. Specially when you need to extract from just one object.

If you have a list of object. Map through the list and extract in every iteration.

```
function objectExtract(obj, properties) {
    return properties.reduce((result, prop) => {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            result[prop] = obj[prop];
        }
        return result;
    }, {});
}
```

Read about **reduce** here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce .

### use:

(a real example with redux)

```
store.dispatch(
            setRooms({ 
                ...roomsState,
                list: rooms.reduce((list, room) => {
                    list[room.id] = objectExtract(room, ['name', 'description', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt']);
                    return list;
                }, {})
            })
        )
```

(On the example of the question)

```
var dataSourceArray = [{
  "att1": "something",
  "att2": "something",
  "att20": "something",
  "att100": "something"
}, {
  "att1": "something",
  "att2": "something",
  "att20": "something",

  "att100": "something"
}];

let x = dataSourceArray.map((item) => {
  return objectExtrac(item, ['att100', 'att2']);
});
```

Comment: Somehow the spread operator `...` in other answers is getting me troubles. The genuine function `objectExtract` works perfectly for me.