# Object Filter Using JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to filter selected property from object using JavaScript.

**This is my array**

```
const odata=[
  {
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
  },
  {
    "id": "0002",
    "type": "ansd",
    "name": "EARK",
    "ppu": 0.67,
  }
];
```

I want output like this - I want to select only 2 (id,type) props from the object

```
[
  {"id": "0001","type": "donut"}
  {"id": "0002","type": "ansd"}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and some [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the desired result.

The destructuring assignment syntax allows us to get selected values from Objects and Arrays in a convenient way.

```js
const odata= [ { "id": "0001", "type": "donut", "name": "Cake", "ppu": 0.55, }, { "id": "0002", "type": "ansd", "name": "EARK", "ppu": 0.67, } ];

const result = odata.map(({ id, type}) => ({ id, type }));
console.log("Result:", result)
```

Comment: i have find more easy way to do this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68376616/4208247

Answer (score 1):

User `Array.prototype.map()` for generating a new array from an existing one.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const odata = [
  { "id": "0001", "type": "donut", "name": "Cake", "ppu": 0.55 },
  { "id": "0002", "type": "ansd", "name": "EARK", "ppu": 0.67 }
];
const output = odata.map(node => ({
    id: node.id,
    type: node.type,
}))
console.log(output)
```