# How to treat JSON data in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json

I am using the following code using a flight data API:

```
useEffect(() => {

fetch(url, options)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        datos.push(json)
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log('error' + err));
    }, []);

return (
    <div className='ejemplo'>
        {JSON.stringify(datos)}
    <div\>
    )
```

and this is the result in the DOM:

`[{"success":true,"data":{"2023-02-08":{"origin":"MAD","destination":"BCN","price":88,"airline":"UX","flight_number":7701,"departure_at":"2023-02-08T07:30:00+01:00","return_at":"2023-02-12T11:50:00+01:00","transfers":0,"expires_at":"2023-02-07T08:27:20Z"},"2023-02-09":{"origin":"MAD","destination":"BCN","price":69,"airline":"IB","flight_number":3034,"departure_at":"2023-02-09T21:15:00+01:00","return_at":"2023-02-13T18:05:00+01:00","transfers":0,"expires_at":"2023-02-07T08:27:20Z"},"2023-02-14":{"origin":"MAD","destination":"BCN","price":69,"airline":"IB","flight_number":3012,"departure_at":"2023-02-14T11:30:00+01:00","return_at":"2023-02-18T21:05:00+01:00","transfers":0,"expires_at":"2023-02-07T08:27:20Z"},"2023-02-15":{"origin":"MAD","destination":"BCN","price":69,"airline":"IB","flight_number":3034,"departure_at":"2023-02-15T21:15:00+01:00","return_at":"2023-02-19T14:30:00+01:00","transfers":0,"expires_at":"2023-02-07T08:27:20Z"},"2023-02-16":{"origin":"MAD","destination":"BCN","price":87,"airline":"IB","flight_number":3018,"departure_at":"2023-02-16T16:00:00+01:00","return_at":"2023-02-20T12:35:00+01:00","transfers":0,"expires_at":"2023-02-07T08:27:20Z"},"2023-02-17":{"origin":"MAD","destination":"BCN","price":57,"airline":"IB","flight_number":5003,"departure_at":"2023-02-17T22:20:00+01:00","return_at":"2023-02-21T20:30:00+01:00","transfers":0,"expires_at":"2023-02-07T08:27:20Z"},"2023-02-19":{"origin":"MAD","destination":"BCN","price":63,"airline":"UX","flight_number":7701,"departure_at":"2023-02-19T07:30:00+01:00","return_at":"2023-02-23T20:30:00+01:00","transfers":0,"expires_at":"2023-02-07T08:27:20Z"},"2023-02-21":{"origin":"MAD","destination":"BCN","price":69,"airline":"IB","flight_number":3012,"departure_at":"2023-02-21T11:30:00+01:00","return_at":"2023-02-25T14:30:00+01:00","transfers":0,"expires_at":"2023-02-07T08:27:20Z"},"2023-02-23":{"origin":"MAD","destination":"BCN","price":52,"airline":"UX","flight_number":7701,"departure_at":"2023-02-23T07:30:00+01:00","return_at":"2023-02-27T11:50:00+01:00","transfers":0,"expires_at":"2023-02-07T08:27:20Z"}`

How can I modify my code in order to obtain just the origin, destination and price attributes? Thanks you all.

I tried to add a . plus the search attributes but no correct response was given.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract certain properties from all objects in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52153345/extract-certain-properties-from-all-objects-in-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop your `data` by key and create a custom array of objects:

```
const [datos, setDatos] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {

    fetch(url, options)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => {
            const { success, data } = json;
            if (!success) console.log(error);
            else {
                const dataList = [];
                for (const key in data) {
                    const { origin, destination, price } = data[key];
                    dataList.push({ origin, destination, price });
                }
                setDatos(dataList);
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log('error' + err));
        }, []);
    
    return (
        <div className='ejemplo'>
            {
                datos.length > 0 && datos.map((d, index) => {
                    return <div key={index}>
                        <p>{d.origin}</p>
                        <p>{d.destination}</p>
                        <p>{d.price}</p>
                    </div>
                }
            }
        </div>
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract only the desired attributes by using object destructuring in the `.then` function. Here's an example:

```
.then((json) => {
    const {data} = json;
    const flightData = Object.values(data).map(({origin, destination, price}) => ({origin, destination, price}));
    datos.push(flightData);
})
```

In this example, `Object.values(data)` is used to get an array of flight data objects from the `data` object. Then, `.map` is used to extract only the `origin`, `destination`, and `price` properties from each object and create a new array of flight data objects with just those properties. This new array is then pushed to the `datos` array.

Comment: I am obtaining the follow result:   [[{"origin":"MAD","destination":"BCN","price":88},{"origin":"MAD","destination":"BCN","price":69},{"origin":"MAD","destination":"BCN","price":69},{"origin":"MAD","destination":"BCN","price":69},{"origin":"MAD","destination":"BCN","price":87}, How can I only get the results not the attribute?